# Jquery error in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have been trying to figure this out for the past couple hours and was hoping someone here could help out. I am using JQuery 1.6.4 to make an ajax call when a button is clicked and populate the contents of a table with the results. The code works as it should in all browsers except IE. When i run it in IE, some values are populated and the rest are not, very strange!

When i run the script and use IE's debugging tool i get the following error;

> Unexpected call to method or property access (line 3)

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong? Here is my code that runs the ajax;

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#find").click(function ()    {

    //Set kinase
    var kinaseEntry = $("#kinaseEntry").val();
    var dataString = "kinaseEntry=" + kinaseEntry;

    //Fetch list from database
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "http://www.webaddress/php/post.php",
        datatype: "json",
        data:   dataString,
        success : function(datas)   {

            //SET VARIABLES TO BE USED THROUGHOUT PAGE
            var kinaseName = (datas.skuName);
            var molecularWeight = (datas.molecularWeight);
            var kinaseConc = (datas.kinaseConc);
            var anti1Name = (datas.antiName);
            var anti2Name = (datas.antiName2);
            var antiConc = (datas.antiConc);
            var antiConc2 = (datas.antiConc2);
            var tracerName = (datas.tracerName);
            var tracerConc = (datas.tracerConc);
            var tracerStockConc = (datas.tracerStockConc);
            var tracerSku = (datas.tracerSku);
            var kinaseSku = (datas.kinaseSku);
            var antiSku = (datas.antiSku);
            var antiSku2 = (datas.antiSku2);
            var bufferName = (datas.bufferName);
            var bufferSku = (datas.bufferSku);

            //REAGENT NAMES
            $(".kinaseName").html(kinaseName + " (" + molecularWeight + " kDa)");
            $(".anti1Name").html(anti1Name);
            $(".anti2Name").html(anti2Name);
            $(".tracerName").html(tracerName);
            $(".bufferName").html(bufferName);

            //DEFAULT VALUES
            $(".defaultKinaseConc").html(kinaseConc);
            $(".defaultAntiConc").html(antiConc);
            $(".defaultAnti2Conc").html(antiConc2);
            $(".defaultTracerConc").html(tracerConc);
            $("#molecularWeight").val(molecularWeight);
            $("#tracerStockConc").val(tracerStockConc);

            //INSERT DEFAULTS INTO INPUT
            $("#userKinaseConc").val(kinaseConc);
            $("#userAntibodyConc1").val(antiConc);
            $("#userAntibodyConc2").val(antiConc2);
            $("#userTracerConc").val(tracerConc);
        },
        error : function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("error :"+XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
}); });
```

The names populate fine and the first default value gets populated, but the rest breaks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the results of my console.log();

```
antiConc
    "2"

antiConc2
    "2"

antiName
    "Biotin-anti-His"

antiName2
    "Eu-Streptavidin"

antiSku
    "PV6089"

antiSku2
    "PV5899"

bufferName
    "Kinase Buffer A"

bufferSku
    "PV3189"

cleanSKU
    null

kinaseConc
    "5"

kinaseSku
    "P3049"

molecularWeight
    "125.4"

skuName
    "ABL1"

tracerConc
    "100"

tracerName
    "Kinase Tracer 1710"

tracerSku
    "PV6088"

tracerStockConc
    "25"
```

Comment: Can you log `datas` variable with `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: @Nicola i can see the datas console log in FF, but not ie

Comment: If you are testing in IE8+ you have a debugger, press F12 then refresh the page. You can still show us the log from FF, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: The error (on line 3) suggests you're using a minified version of jquery. You could try including the raw jquery library (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js) to see if you can get better focus on where in jquery IE is throwing an exception and debug from there.

Comment: have narrowed it down to the following block of code `// resolve with given context and args

resolveWith:

function ( context, args ) { if ( !cancelled && !fired && !firing ) { // make sure args are available (#8421)
args = args || [];

firing = 1;

try { while ( callbacks[ 0 ] ) {
callbacks.shift().apply( context, args );

}

}

finally {
fired = [ context, args ];

firing = 0;

}

}

return this ;
},`

Comment: It seems there is a `try` block without any `catch`... Can you try to add the catch block ?

Comment: Yeah, there's some discussion about this at http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9033 - the bug is closed as fixed, but the actual fix was rolled out for given reasons. Another comment (#19) advises that this only appears to affect IE8 (silently handled properly by FF, Chrome, etc). Reproduced by that commenter when object notification is returned with a stray commenter. @JPK - you've included values returned above, but can you look at the JSON (presumed) itself to make sure it's well-formed?

Comment: I managed to find the problem. I started deleteing chunks of code until everything worked. the problem lay in the html tables, where there was a rogue input box that had the wrong class. This was breaking my whole code! Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's working *properly* in other browsers, or are they just not breaking as significantly.

I'm guessing you have mixed updates happening here (a distinction presumed from val() and html() use). I notice a pattern whereby elements retrieved by id (e.g., #userKinaseConc) and those retrieved by class (e.g., .kinaseName) are using val() and html() respectively. However, #defAntiCon breaks that pattern. You're using html() for this element.  Is this element an input or other form field? Should this be val()?

The experience you describe can be [re-created](http://jsfiddle.net/6FU33/4/) by attempting to apply a value to an input field via html() setter rather than val(), with the exception that it still doesn't work for that specific field in all values... browsers other than IE just fail differently and the error becomes non-breaking. In IE, it will break execution. Is #defAntiCon actually being populated based on data returned in other browsers?

Comment: my table has empty cells that i would like values inserted using the .html() and some cells have input boxes that a user can manipulate, hence the .val(). When i run int in FF i got 0 errors and all fields are populated correctly

Comment: @JPK - Figured it was something like that. I suppose what I was asking could have been more succinctly, "what kind of element is #defAntiConc?" [more fitting for a comment than an answer] ... however, if it's getting value populated outside of IE, then it's almost certainly not what I was speculating.

Comment: apologies i had a typo in my posted code. I have updated that line. To be more clear, the default values are all td elements, with the exception of the last 2, they are hidden input boxes. The "defaults into inputs" are all input boxes

Answer (score 0):

IE8 Is strict about HTML insertion. If your markup is invalid, or either have HTML5 specific tags, it will throw an error.

I have no real solution, but I'd follow this steps to make it works.

1. Make sure your `datas` contains valid HTML, make sure you have no extra closing tags or syntax error (you can use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) if needed)
2. If you are using HTML5 tags, you could try to use [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to make sure the browser will understand all the tags
3. Make sur you don't use `.val()` instead of `.html()` in some cases
4. You should replace `.html(datas.foo)` by `.text(datas.foo)` since you are passing string to the method.
5. In case you don't find any solutions, you could add a `catch` block in jQuery `resolveWith` method (referring to your comment) by doing the following changes :

replace this :

```
resolveWith: function ( context, args ) { 
    if ( !cancelled && !fired && !firing ) { 
        // make sure args are available (#8421) 
        args = args || []; firing = 1;
        try {
            while ( callbacks[ 0 ] ) { callbacks.shift().apply( context, args ); } 
        } finally { 
            fired = [ context, args ]; 
            firing = 0; 
        }
    }
    return this ;
},
```

with this :

```
resolveWith: function ( context, args ) { 
    if ( !cancelled && !fired && !firing ) { 
        // make sure args are available (#8421) 
        args = args || []; firing = 1;
        try {
            while ( callbacks[ 0 ] ) { callbacks.shift().apply( context, args ); } 
        } catch (err) {

        } finally { 
            fired = [ context, args ]; 
            firing = 0; 
        }
    }
    return this ;
},
```

Bug on the `try-finally` in IE [is reported here](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-184-catch-to-try-catch-finally-in.html)

Hope this helps.

**Edit :** As @Josh mentionned in the comment, the bug [has been reported](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9033) and resolved in [this commit](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/4092e3d2754e3847cd3159edb23184d4cfd4cf03) for **jQuery 1.7.x**. A simple update of your jQuery should works.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @Rayfranco. I have validated my code () with the exception of autocomplete="off", which i have tested without), i am not using html5 tags, i am only using val() for the input boxes, html() for td elements and i already tried changing the html() to text(), gave me the same result.

Comment: Darn. You definitely should add the result of `console.log(datas)` to your question. Even if catch up in FF or Chrome.

Comment: So for sure you need to replace `.html()` by `.text()` since you are not trying to insert HTML but strings. Have you tried to replace ALL the `.html()` methods yet ?

Comment: Yes, but i still get the same result

Comment: I've added a solution, not the easiest one, but it should work (I have not tried it). It seems that IE don't like `try-finally` without the `catch` block.

Comment: Yeah - I think @rayfranco is on the right track with catch, however I don't know modifying the core code is the precise action to take. See http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9033 comment #19. (note: bug shows fixed with a catch block, but fixed was rolled out... identified resolved in 1.7.x.

Comment: Thanks @Josh for the bug report. So you maybe should try to upgrade your jQuery version...